# IF ELSE condition on ORACLE

Tags: oracle, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a sql request on Oracle but i'hve a little probleme. I've this sentence to translate and I don't know how.. Can you help me ? How can I translate it ? :(

```
IF(CODE="fuu")
THEN(SELECT bar FROM TABLE)
ELSE(we return 0)
```

Thx in advice.

EDIT :

My request is like that

```
SELECT distinct
  A, B, C, D, E,
  SUM(F+G+H) AS "FGH",
  SUM(I -(FGH)) AS "I",
  CASE WHEN code='fuu' THEN bar ELSE 0 END AS AS "What I need"
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE 
  A=20
GROUP BY
  A, B, C, D, E;
```

This solution works but i'don't have the good answer for it. Actually is should have for A=20 -> bar = 7598 and not 0;

Comment: Do you wan to do this in SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: I'ld like to do this in SQL.

Comment: What is wrong with `select bar from the_table where code = 'fuu';`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Your solution is perfect cause that return 0 when the code is not fuu. But I've the next error : 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized it doesn't work with your `GROUP BY`. We need to know how the `code` and `bar` columns relate to the `(A,B,C,D,E)` grouping. Some sample input and output would probably help make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner in sql requestand thx you for helping me. Well, I don't really understand what you need more, all is here. I need to Group By (A,B,C,D,E) cause I use the function SUM for (F,G,H,I). code and bar are in the same table than A,B,C,etc.. Maybe sould I use a nvl2() function like this : nvl2(code='fuu',bar,0); ?

Comment: `GROUP BY` means you are using multiple input rows to build a single output row. So you can have multiple different values of `code` and `bar` in the same group. You could use aggregate functions on them, like you did on `F`, `G`, `H`, and `I`, but I don't think `SUM(code)` will be right since it is apparently not a numeric field.

Comment: Yes F, G, H, and I are numeric. I've edit my first post. Your answer worked well, I just needed to add 'fuu' and code' on the Group By expression. But for the line A, the answer is 7598 and not 0; That's strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A case expression in SQL is an equivalent to IF statement in other languages:

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 [ ELSE value2 ] END
```

I guess that you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT distinct
  A, B, C, D, E,
  SUM(F+G+H) AS "FGH",
  SUM(I -(FGH)) AS "I",
  CASE WHEN CODE='fuu' THEN bar ELSE 0 END As "What I need"
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE 
  A=20
GROUP BY
  A, B, C,  D, E, "What I need"
```